# How to create top-level named volume with a relative path for the source?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose version 2, I set up one container with relative path mappings like:

```
volumes:
   - ./local:/var/www/local
   - ./another:/var/www/another
```

Then I used volumes_from for other services to reuse the same volume and paths.

Since compose version 3 removed volumes_from, I'm trying to create a named top-level volume that can be used for every service, but I don't see how to use a relative path. Since this is for local development, the absolute path can be different among developers.

The other option is to copy the above volumes configuration into every service that needs it, but as I understand it'll create a new volume for each one and add overhead for syncing. What's the solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use driver options. Example

```
services:
  web:
    image: ubuntu
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
      - mydata:/test

volumes:
  mydata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      device: $PWD
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using a relative path like this: `device: "$PWD/../../another_dir"`.